# How to test in jest for target instanceof window.Window

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, jsdom, ts-jest

I have a function that performs the following (NOTE: this is using typescript hence the type defs you see in the args)...

```
function scroll(target: HTMLElement, {posX, posY}: ScrollPosition): void {
    if (target instanceof window.Window) {
        target.scrollTo(posX, posY);
    } else {
        /* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */
        target.scrollLeft = posX;
        target.scrollTop = posY;
        /* eslint-enable no-param-reassign */
    }
}
```

With the current jest setup that I have, it covers for the else statement, but I need to also test when `target instanceof window.Window`. This is some of what I have so far at least to get a spy on the scrollTo...

```
const spyScrollTo = jest.fn();

beforeEach(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(global.window, 'scrollTo', {value: spyScrollTo});
    spyScrollTo.mockClear();
});
```

...but I haven't gotten far enough along to figure out how to make the target getting passed as part of `window.Window`. I've tried messing around with the jsdom library with little success.

Comment: What's the purpose of `instanceof window.Window` check? Is it supposed to handle iframes? It may not work as expected in Jest.

Answer (score 1):

`window.scrollTo` property descriptor should be `configurable` in order to be set multiple times. It should be cleaned up in `afterEach` to avoid test cross-contamination.

Currently `window === global` and not an instance of `Window` in Jest, so it won't pass `target instanceof window.Window` condition which would be true in a browser.

It can be tested with stubbed `Window` instance:

```
test('...', () => {
  let mockWindow = Object.create(Window.prototype, { scrollTo: { value: jest.fn() } });
  scroll(mockWindow, {posX: 100, posY: 200});
  expect(mockWindow.scrollTo).toBeCalledWith(100, 200);
});
```

Comment: Oh excellent!!! I just got back from out of town, but I will test this out and mark as answered if it works out. Thank you so much @Estus. This is clever.

Comment: This works as expected. It should have been marked as solving the question.